# Load many images from php file sometimes throw 500 internal server error

Tags: php, image, load, internal-server-error

I'm loading a gallery of many images from the root of the server ("behind" public_html). 
For this job I use a php file which, obtained the name with $_GET, find the image and print it like in the code.

Nothing strange, if not that when the images are many, I get an highly variable number of 500 internal server error.

I'm doing this because I wanted to dynamically manipulate their width/height and maybe adding a watermark. But at the moment I'm not doing that, first I need to solve this problem.

My doubt is:
- Is the problem that I load all of them with the same file and I overload the php?
- The images loaded in this manner, are correctly cached by the browser?
- If I don't want the user for directly access the images, what should I do?
- Should I just surrender and upload normally the images on public_html?

header('Content-Type: '.mime_content_type($filepath));
readfile($filepath);

Comment: You're probably spinning up more PHP processes than your server can accomodate, _espiecially_ if you're resizing images on-the-fly. The best solution is always going to be to pre-compute various sizes in advance when you upload the image, but if you insist upon on-the-fly resizing you should offload the actual resizing to a queue with a fixed number of workers.

Comment: Also, you can completely offload even the `readfile()` to your webserver with [`X-Sendfile`](https://coderwall.com/p/8lpngg/x-sendfile-in-apache2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "found the solution".
There is no solution. The classic route is hundred times faster than putting PHP in the middle of it.

Theres no way around if the images are many.